# I can't understand getters, setters

Tags: get, set

I have a hard time understanding getters, setters.
I understand that ‘get’ is for accessing a property and ‘set’ is for changing or mutating that property.

But even if I change _numOfSensors to -5 or a “string” it wont give me the error message… I got everything right, but I can’t for the life of me understand how it works. Someone who can explain how this code works more precisely, but also in a simple way? Appreciate all the help, take care!

Language: JavaScript

```
const robot = {
  _model: “1E78V2”,
  _energyLevel: 100,
  _numOfSensors: 15,
  get numOfSensors() {
    if (typeof this._numOfSensors === “number”) {
      return this._numOfSensors;
    } else {
      return “Sensors are currently down.”;
    }
  },
  set numOfSensors(num) {
    if (typeof num === “number” && num >= 0) {
    this._numOfSensors = num;
    } else {
      return “Pass in a number that is greater than or equal to 0”;
    }
  },
};
robot.numOfSensors = 100;
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
```

Well, I've tried to google and look online, but I really don't understand...

Comment: The return value of a setter is essentially ignored, because setters are designed to set a value, not to return one.
The setter is indeed invoked, and it reaches the else block. It then returns the error message "Pass in a number that is greater than or equal to 0". However, this returned value doesn't go anywhere and is not displayed or stored. Hence it's essentially lost!
If you want to make the error noticeable use "Console Log" or use "try-catch block".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try:

```
robot.numOfSensors = 100;
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
robot.numOfSensors = -100;
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
robot.numOfSensors = -5
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
robot.numOfSensors = -17
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
```

You will see:

```
100
100
100
100
```

then try:

```
robot.numOfSensors = -2;
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
robot.numOfSensors = -5;
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
robot.numOfSensors = 8
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
robot.numOfSensors = -17
console.log(robot.numOfSensors);
```

you will get:

```
100
100
8
8
```

This means the if statement make some difference, but the return value will only make sense when you assign the return value of a function to a variable

In my humble view, you can try throwing an exception instead of it.

```
const robot = {
  _model: "1E78V2",
  _energyLevel: 100,
  _numOfSensors: 15,

  get numOfSensors() {
    if (typeof this._numOfSensors === "number") {
      return this._numOfSensors;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Sensors are currently down.");
    }
  },

  set numOfSensors(num) {
    if (typeof num === "number" && num >= 0) {
      this._numOfSensors = num;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Pass in a number that is greater than or equal to 0");
    }
  },
};

try {
  robot.numOfSensors = -5; // Trigger the setter, throw an exception
  console.log(robot.numOfSensors); // This line will not execute because exception is thrown
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message); // Catch the exception and print the error message
}
```

You can see output in your terminal:

```
Pass in a number that is greater than or equal to 0
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! But what does the 'throw new Error' do? I saw an edit in my post that I should change the return to a console.log() instead. And that did the trick as well. But is it the same as just logging it to the console?

Comment: throw new Error interrupts program execution and raises an exception to indicate an error.
console.log() is used for logging messages to the console and does not interrupt program execution.